# Modelling of odds ratio with continuous & categorical covariates

Tags: bayesian, mixed-model, odds-ratio, systematic-review

We've completed a systematic review of % diagnosed among female sex workers (FSW) living with HIV across Sub-Saharan Africa (SSA). In our **Objective 1**, we model this proportion $p_s$ as:
\begin{aligned}
y_s &\sim \textrm{binom}(p_s,n_s) \\
\textrm{logit}(p_s) &= \epsilon_s
+ R_s (\alpha_r + \beta_r t)
\end{aligned}
where:

- $y_s$ is the observed count diagnosed among $n_s$ respondents in survey $s$
- $\epsilon_s$ is a random study effect;
- $R_s$ and $r$ denote 1 of 4 SSA region of study $s$
- $\alpha_r$ and $\beta_r$ are intercept and slope w.r.t. (centered) calendar year $t$

If relevant, we solve the model in a Bayesian framework with priors on
$\epsilon_s$, $\alpha_r$, $\beta_r$.

In our **Objective 2**, we want to infer the *relative* proportions among FSW vs women overall (WO) within each country-year -- this could be as odds-ratio or risk ratio. We want to consider possible differences in the relative proportions w.r.t. year and region. So, we propose the following model:

\begin{aligned}
y_s &\sim \textrm{binom}(p_s,n_s) \\
\textrm{logit}(p_s) &= \epsilon_s
+ R_s (\alpha_r + \beta_r t)
+ P_s R_s (\alpha_{pr} + \beta_{pr} t)
\end{aligned}

Where $P_s$ and $p \in \{\textrm{FSW},\textrm{WO}\}$ denote the population of study $s$, and we now include studies of both FSW and WO. FYI, We are mostly interested in simply plotting the point (95% CI) of $p_r = p_s - \epsilon_s$ here.

**Questions:**

1. Is our overall approach to Objective 2 reasonable?
2. Could we interpret $\mathrm{exp}(\alpha_{pr} + \beta_{pr} t)$ as the time-varying odds ratio in % diagnosed among FSW vs women overall in region $r$? I think: *yes*
3. Is it important to find women-overall studies with same years as FSW studies? I think: *not important*
4. Is it important to find all available WO studies? I think: *yes, but this means we need to do another systematic review...*
5. Should we add a country level error term too, beyond $\epsilon_s$? I think: *not sure*